# Express routing - Unauthorized Error handler hanging up the error routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am using this code I grabbed from a tutorial book. I implemented users with passport and the `app.use` checking for `UnauthorizedError` was the tutorials recommended way to check for checking unauthorized access to restricted parts of the application.

Whenever I type a bad url the website just hangs, no error handling and no message sent to the browser. I spent a good part of yesterday checking my routes and there seemed to be no glaring issue.

Then today with a small hunch I commented out the error check for `Unauthorized error` and voila error handling is all good again. Any suggestion for what's happening here and how could I implement this error check properly?

Note: when there's an actual unauthorized access to a known url good route, this error check does work. However it still does not catch bad url even if logged in.

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', routesApi);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);  
});

// error handlers
// Catch unauthorised errors
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401);
    res.json({"message" : err.name + ": " + err.message});
  }
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, you must call next() to forwarding error to next error handler.

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401);
    res.json({"message" : err.name + ": " + err.message});
  } else
    next(err);
});
```

Comment: Not perhaps... that was it!